# How to pass Extracted value in a single varaible by using json and dammy sampler

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw9U1.png) [How to pass Extracted value in a single varaible  by using json and dammy sampler i.e ${tokenvalue}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NVKI.png)

[see below images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NVKI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following configuration:

- Match No: `-1`
- Compute concatenation var: `true`

You will have 2 variables generated:

1. `${token_value_1}`
2. `${token_value_ALL}`

You can check JMeter Variables names and values using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

If you want a **single** variable which will match your `${token_value}` definition you will need to amend JSON Extractor configuration to look like:

[image: JMeter JSON Extractor]

References:

- [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)
- [JSON Path Examples](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples)